# Finding the stationary point with implicit differentiation

Tags: derivatives

I want to find the stationary points of the curve $y^3+3xy^2-x^3=3$

I differentiate to get
$\frac{x^2-y^2}{y^2+2xy}$

and so $x^2-y^2=0$ but I have two unknowns and I'm not sure how to solve.

Comment: sorry I made an error its meant to be $3xy^2$

Comment: You have either $x=y$ or $x=-y$. Substitute back to the original equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah you're on the right track... you just gotta keep going.
\begin{align} \frac{x^2-y^2}{y^2+2xy} = 0\ \\
\\
\implies y(y+2x) \neq 0\quad \text{and}\quad (x+y)(x-y) = 0\\
\\
\implies (y \neq 0\quad \text{and}\quad y \neq -2x)\quad \text{and}\quad (x=y\quad \text{or}\quad x = -y).\\
\end{align}
$$$$
Now substitute $x = y$ back into the original equation $\ y^3+3xy^2-x^3=3\ $ to find the coordinate of the stationary point corresponding to when $x = y$.

Then do a similar back-substitution for when $\ x = -y\ $ to find the coordinate of the other stationary point.

Comment: Aah thank you so much I get it now! :D

Comment: No problemo amigo!